# Can a counter_cache be used with a has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working to add a counter_cache to my models:

Users (id, org_id)
   Orgs (id, users_count)

But get the following error: `ArgumentError (Unknown key(s): counter_cache):`

```
class Org < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users, :counter_cache => true

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :org
```

Any ideas what is setup wrong. I would like Org.users_count to return the counter_cache for the # of users in that org?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't work this way. You have to move the counter_cache to the belongs_to:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :org, :counter_cache => true
end
```

And add a `users_count` field to the `Org` model and then Rails will update the field for you. Don't forget to add a `:default=> 0` in the migration, otherwise it won't work fine.

If you have already some data in your app and you want to sync the counter, you can run (after the migration) something like the following:

```
  Org.find(:all).each do |o|
    Org.update_counters o.id, :users_count => o.users.count
  end
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have helped. What's the best way to trigger a reset for existing records? Can I run it as a rake task given I've already run the migration?

Comment: I've edited the question. You can run that code with `rails runner`