# PostgreSQL 9.6 stored procedure performance improvement

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, database-trigger

i have two tables `users` and `products` and the association between them is that `User has many products`. I want to store the count of products in the users table and it should be updated at every insert or delete. So i have written a stored procedure in the database for it and trigger to fire it. The problem is when i am inserting thousands of products at once it is executing the trigger `per row insertion` and it is taking too much time.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION update_product_count()
  RETURNS trigger AS $$
  BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
      UPDATE users SET products_count = products_count - 1 WHERE id = OLD.user_id;
    END IF;

    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
      UPDATE users SET products_count = products_count + 1 WHERE id = NEW.user_id;
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

  CREATE TRIGGER update_user_products_count
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON products
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_product_count();
```

**UPDATE**

1. i have added: `SET CONSTRAINTS update_promotion_products_count DEFERRED;`
   but seems like it is not making any progress because right now it is taking 6100ms which is somewhat similar to before.
2. Tried `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` but it is still not working. I think `FOR EACH ROW` is the actual issue. But when i tried it with `FOR EACH STATEMENT` it throws statement invalid error.
3. Rewrote the above procedure like this:

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION update_product_count()
    RETURNS trigger AS $$
     BEGIN
       IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' OR TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
         UPDATE users SET products_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM products WHERE products.user_id = users.id);
       END IF;

       RETURN NULL;
     END;
     $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

   CREATE TRIGGER update_user_products_count
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON products
   FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_product_count();
   ```

But the problem is then when you have 1000 usres with 10000 products each, you recalculate the count of every user (even when just insert a single product in the database)

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? With Postgres 10 you could do this with a statement level trigger

Comment: The version is 9.6. Updated in the question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name any ideas ?

Comment: @Ahmad: You could write a row-level trigger which queues up changes in a temp table, and a statement-level trigger which applies the changes at the end: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47909709

Comment: @NickBarnes I'm sorry but actually i dont exactly understand it. It would be great if you can write in question's context in the answer so that i can better talk to you about it and mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a_horse_with_no_name noted in comments, Postgres 10 can do this much more efficiently using a `FOR EACH STATEMENT` trigger which updates all `users` records at once based on the statement's [transition table](https://www.depesz.com/2017/06/02/waiting-for-postgresql-10-implement-syntax-for-transition-tables-in-after-triggers/).

In earlier versions, you can get some of the benefit by queueing the changes in a temp table, and applying them at the end of the statement with a single `UPDATE`.

Initialise the queue at the start of the statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION create_queue_table() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMP TABLE pending_changes(user_id INT UNIQUE, count INT) ON COMMIT DROP;
  RETURN NULL;
END
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER create_queue_table_if_not_exists
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF user_id OR DELETE
  ON products
  FOR EACH STATEMENT
  WHEN (to_regclass('pending_changes') IS NULL)
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_queue_table();
```

Record the change for each row:

```
CREATE FUNCTION queue_change() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP IN ('DELETE', 'UPDATE') THEN
    INSERT INTO pending_changes (user_id, count) VALUES (old.user_id, -1)
    ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO UPDATE SET count = pending_changes.count - 1;
  END IF;

  IF TG_OP IN ('INSERT', 'UPDATE') THEN
    INSERT INTO pending_changes (user_id, count) VALUES (new.user_id, 1)
    ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO UPDATE SET count = pending_changes.count + 1;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER queue_change
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF user_id OR DELETE
  ON products
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE queue_change();
```

Apply the changes at the end of the statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION process_pending_changes() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE users
  SET products_count = products_count + pending_changes.count
  FROM pending_changes
  WHERE users.id = pending_changes.user_id;

  DROP TABLE pending_changes;
  RETURN NULL;
END
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER process_pending_changes
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF user_id OR DELETE
  ON products
  FOR EACH STATEMENT
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_pending_changes();
```

This may or may not be noticeably faster, depending on the details of your case, but it performed significantly better in an artificial test ([184ms](http://rextester.com/EYSPB14152) vs. [4073ms](http://rextester.com/DDGJ86440)).

As I noted in a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47909709), this implementation has some potential deadlocks which you might want to address if you're running this concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

In your case count will not update when user_id of the product gets change,
So, i'll recommend [`counter_cache`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9400828/297087) of rails

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
end
```

Also have a look at this [gem](https://github.com/wanelo/counter-cache)

Note :- This will not solve your `per row insertion` problem though

You have to write custom counter then, something like following

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
  attr_accessor :update_count

  belongs_to :user#, counter_cache: true

  after_save do
    update_counter_cache
  end

  after_destroy do
    update_counter_cache
  end

  def update_counter_cache
    return unless update_count
    user.products_count = user.products.count
    user.save
  end
end
```

in rails console

```
10.times{|n| Product.new(name: "Latest New Product #{n}", update_count: n == 9, user_id: user.id).save}
```

Comment: per row insertion is my problem because i'm inserting 20k records at once.